# Mysql find row with longest field value as beginning of a text

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have something like this in a mysql table.

```
ID  Text
1   a
2   b
3   a-b
4   b-a
5   a-b-c
6   a-b-d
```

Usually you search a text inside a column, i just want the opposite, *i want a query to search all columns inside a text*. I dont know if it is possible.

> if text is "**a-b-f**" It must return query with ID **3** ("a-b")
>
> if text is "**a-c**" It must return query with ID **1** ("a")
>
> if text is "**b-a**" It must return query with ID **2** ("b")
>
> if text is "**b-b**" It must return query with ID **2** ("b")
>
> if text is "**a-b-c-d-e-f**" It must return query with ID **5** ("a-b-c")
>
> if text is "**c-a-a**" It must return an **empty** query

Thanks for the help.

PD: I was looking for something like this but all ways I found was search a text inside a column value and it is the opposite way as I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be using like

```
 select ID from my_table  
 where  'your_text_seach'   like   concat ( text, '%')
 order by length(text) desc
 limit 1
```

Comment: It is returning more than one line when text is "a-b-c" for example.. it returns ID 1, 3 and 5, it must return the longest string, probaby just sort by  string size and limit to 1

Comment: I have upate the answer .. let me know

Comment: There is a small tipo error (length), but it is working, thanks